# interval parent function in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state, intervals

i'm trying to pass a parent function to a child component in react and set an interval in child component to call parent function ..i know seems easy but i'm new in react.
i get this error "this.func is not a function" after first interval execution
here is my code ..

```
export default class Child extends React.Component{
    func;
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.func = props.func;
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        setInterval(() => {this.func() }, 1000);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{this.props.value}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
import React from 'react';
import Child from './child';
export default class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            counter:0
        }
    }
    increase() {
        this.setState({counter:this.state.counter+1});
    }
   
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child proc={this.increase} value={this.state.counter}></Child>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your parent you pass the prop `proc` to your child.

```
import React from 'react';
import Child from './child';
export default class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            counter:0
        }
    }
    increase() {
        this.setState({counter:this.state.counter+1});
    }
   
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child proc={this.increase} value={this.state.counter}></Child>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

In the child component first pass your `props` to the `super` keyword. There is no need to store the function in a property of the `Child` component as it will always exist as a passed property.

Call the function by using the same keyword you used to pass the prop down. In this case `proc`.

```
export default class Child extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.props.proc() 
        }, 1000);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{this.props.value}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much it works..although i had to add bind(this) to func in parent..

Answer (score 1):

let fix on 2 thing:

- Bind parent to method `bind(this)`: When you call this.func() from `Child`, it still execute by `Parent` object.

```js
<Child proc={this.increase.bind(this)} value={this.state.counter}></Child>
```

- func get by props.proc on Child, because send by `proc={this.increase.bind(this)}`

```js
constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.func = props.proc;
    }
```

Goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

For child - parent communication you should pass a function setting the state from parent to child, like this

```
export default class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
         counter : 0
    }
    this.increase = this.increase.bind(this)
  }

  increase() {
     this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 });
  }

  render() {
    return (
         <div>
            <Child proc={this.increase} value={this.state.counter}></Child>
         </div>
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
  }
  componentDidMount() {
     setInterval(() => {this.props.proc() }, 1000);
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{this.props.value}</p>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
This way the child can update the parent's state with the call of a function passed with props.
```